# Uninitialized variable when processing without alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a log reader in Javascript/jQuery/PHP that displays the content of a text-file in an ingrid table.

The Javascript-part has the following functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  // Count number of lines in the log file
  var $anzahlElemente=0;
  $.countLines = function() {
    $.get("../log.log", function(text) {
      var $lines = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
      $anzahlElemente = $lines.length-1;
    });
  };

  // Generate table
  $.showTable = function() {
    $("#table1").ingrid({
      url: 'ingrid.php',
      height: 625,
      initialLoad: true,
      rowClasses: ['grid-row-style1','grid-row-style1','grid-row-style2','grid-row-style1','grid-row-style1','grid-row-style3'],
      sorting: false,
      paging: true,
      totalRecords: $anzahlElemente
    });
  }

$.countLines();
$.showTable();
});
</script>
```

The problem now is that there seems to be a problem with the order or the sequence the functions process. After the two functions are done, the `$anzahlElemente` is still 0. `$anzahlElemente` is needed to display the tables paging function.

The weird thing is, when I try the following, the first alert shows "0" and the second one the correct number of lines. Without the alerts, the number of elements and the paging-function is missing. But with them, all works correctly, besides that I don't want to have these alerts. ;)

```
$.countLines();
alert($anzahlElemente);
alert($anzahlElemente);
$.showTable();
```

Do you need all other parts, like the html, php, css and images or do you see my mistake(s) directly?

**EDIT:** I hope it is allowed to attach files. I didn't find an upload option so I did it on this way: 
[ingrid.zip](http://www.file-upload.net/download-7795935/ingrid.zip.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a common misconception of how javascript code involving asyncronous I/O is executed. In your code showTable is actually executed before the named variable is set due to `$.get` being asyncronous

you could change your code to

```
var countLines = function(renderTable) {
    $.get("../log.log", function(text) {
      var $lines = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
      showTable($lines.length-1)
    });
};
// Generate table
var showTable = function(anzahlElemente) {
    $("#table1").ingrid({
      url: 'ingrid.php',
      height: 625,
      initialLoad: true,
      rowClasses: ['grid-row-style1',
                   'grid-row-style1',
                   'grid-row-style2',
                   'grid-row-style1',
                   'grid-row-style1',
                   'grid-row-style3'],
      sorting: false,
      paging: true,
      totalRecords: anzahlElemente
    });
}

$(function() {
  countLines(showTable);
});
```

in this manner the `showTable` will only execute when the `$.get` is successful.

In a little more details. The call to countLines actually ends before the call to `$.get` does and in your code your are then executing the call to showTable prior to the `$.get` calling executing the callback (the anonymous function setting `$anzahlElemente`. When you insert the alert you are changing the timing giving the call to said callback enough time to execute.

Comment: Hello Rune, thank you for your fast reply!
I'm afraid that your code doesn't work in my case. I guess that there is another problem.
I am going to attach the whole project to my first post so you hopefully can see my problem.

Comment: Rune's code looked good to me, except for one typo I noticed: the `$.countLines(showTable);` call at the end should be `countLines(showTable);`. But you would have gotten a specific error message in the JavaScript console about this. Do you test your code with the JavaScript developer tools? If not, then [read about the Chrome DevTools here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: Don't ask me what I did wrong earlier but your solution works for me now, Rune! Operates perfectly right now.
Thank you very much! And you as well, Michael und Uni!

Answer (score 0):

Try `$.countLines().end().showTable();`.